# Shia Muslims should curse Abram, Jacob and Isaac etc.?

Tags: shiism, prophets

I was told that the Shia Muslims, unlike Sunni Muslims, has got one of the central commandments to curse Abraham, Jacob, Isaac, Moses, David and Sara, Rabeca, Rachel and Lea. Is that true or not? If it is true, then what's the reason for that?

I'm really asking to understand the theme.

Comment: I came to this via email notification and it really seems like a troll question. Why on Earth should Shias curse Israelite Prophets that are admired in Quran? Please delete this as it smears the Shias.

Comment: You're right. It doesn't make sense. (I'm not a troll but I think I was a little bit naive that I believed such stupid thing. I'm really not into that). I'm trying to delete it but I can't because someone already answered an answer. If he'll delete it I'll delete it too.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not true. Infact it is the first time I am hearing this outrageous allegation. The person who told you this is either lying or is ignorant and confusing it with the Twelver Shia stance on the caliphs.

Shia believe in the Quran just like Sunnis. Abraham, Jacob, Isaac, Moses, David  are explicitly named and praised in the Quran, so anyone who curses them denies the Quran, becoming a Kafir.

I recommend you read [3:33](https://legacy.quran.com/3/33) and [6:84-90](https://legacy.quran.com/6/84-90) and [37:109-122](https://legacy.quran.com/37/109-122)

Comment: You're right. It doesn't make sense. (I think I was naive). I'm trying to delete it but I can't because you already answered an answer. If you'll delete it I'll delete it too.